# Is Powershell Sort-Object -ascending deprecated?

Tags: powershell

I tried this in Windows 10 which as far as I know uses latest version of PowerShell :

```
Import-Csv $in -header Date,Time,O,H,L,C,V | Sort-Object H -ascending
```

To my surprise -ascending is not recognized. Why is it deprecated ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge there never was a parameter `-Ascending`. Ascending sort order is the default, while descending needs the parameter `-Descending`.

The oldest language specification I still have lying around is from version 2 and it says this on `Sort-Object`:

[image]

Comment: ok thanks I've been misleaded by this article from Microsoft https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176900.aspx

Comment: Indeed, that's a mistake on that page. If you read on you'll notice that they actually intended to use `-Descending` there: »just use the exact same command but sort in ascending order (the default) rather than descending order«

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Joey posted, there is a way to use Ascending explicitly with `Sort-Object` but you have to use a hashtable. Note this example from [the technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912(v=wps.620).aspx):

```
get-childitem *.txt | sort-object -property @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime}; Ascending=$false} | Format-Table LastWriteTime, CreationTime
```

This allows you to sort some properties as ascending and some as descending. It's strange that they would do it that way, but there it is.

He's still correct though that there is no `-Ascending` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

It's standard Ascending... So that's why you have only the option -Descending